# Get "DIFF" of database after a complex transaction

Tags: sql, database, diff

I have a complex DB and I need to do the following:

after a complex transaction, I need to make some sort of differential report between current database and a second one that repersents first database earlier state, to determine what was added.

There is no need to determine deleted data. I have eg 5-10 tables to compare. So I can do it one by one or all together.

What would be the best SQL expression to reach the goal?

Best, Askar

Comment: 5-10 select statements comparing the values for each table? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tableX,

```
select current_db.tableX.id
from current_db.tableX
  left outer join earlier_db.tableX
    on current_db.tableX.id = earlier_db.tableX.id
where earlier_db.tableX.id is null
```